# How to write for loop inside variable in Javascript or is there an alternative solution?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
$.noConflict(); 
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var queuesArr = new Array();
var i;

for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById('qbeansLength').value; i++){
    queuesArr[i] = document.getElementById('queueID'+i).value}

var data = [
    {
        label: ' Queues',
        children: [
//I need to write the for loop here and make it like this {label: queuesArr[i] } but it is a variable
            { label: document.getElementById('queueID1').value },
            { label: queuesArr[2] }

        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'node2',
        children: [
            { label: 'child3' }
        ]
    }
];

$(function() {
    $('#tree1').tree({
        data: data
    });
});


});
```

Hi, everyone. I am a total newbie in javascript. I need to print a tree on a web page. I use [this widget](http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/#introduction) for it. I need to write the for loop inside a variable but it is a variable so I think it is impossible. Please help me, is there a solution to my problem? The thing is that I dynamically get elements from another jsp page so the amount of children vary as well as the amount of array elements.

Comment: for loop inside a variable? Ah, you want to generate an Array of Objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
$.noConflict(); 
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var data = [
    {
        label: ' Queues',
        children: [
            // Filled in below
        ]
    },
    {
        label: 'node2',
        children: [
            { label: 'child3' }
        ]
    }
];

var queuesArr = new Array();
var i;
var qbeansLength = document.getElementById('qbeansLength').value;
for (i = 0; i < qbeansLength; i++) {
    data[0].children.push({label: document.getElementById('queueID'+i).value});
}

$(function() {
    $('#tree1').tree({
        data: data
    });
});


});
```

Answer (score 2):

To create an array of objects, change your for loop to use [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

```
var myArr = [];
for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById('qbeansLength').value; i++){
    myArr.push( {"label" : document.getElementById('queueID'+i).value });
}
```

and just reference it

```
var data = [
    {
        label: ' Queues',
        children: myArr
    },
```